# Wildcard TDM400P REV H digium card configuration

Tags: linux, asterisk, telephony

I am using the Wildcard TDM400P REV H digium card for making the outbound calls. I have installed the dahdi 2.3.0 and Asterisk 1.6.0.1.

When I am making outbound call I am getting the following error message.

```
app_dial.c:1450 dial_exec_full: Unable to create channel of type 'DAHDI' (cause 34 - Circuit/channel congestion)
```

Any Idea about this error message??? Urgent.

Answer (score 0):

This error just mean card not setuped correctly. Please consult this page: http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/TDM400P

For see what exactly not ok use following commands:

1. To get info about config errors

   dahdi_cfg -vvvv
2. To get more debug in asterisk console

   core set verbose 10

   dahdi set debug on